# After installing ubuntu facing issues while starting windows8.1

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I have successfully installed Ubuntu14.04.2 on my laptop (LENOVO B50-70) alongside windows 8.1 which was pre-installed. After installation I am able to use ubuntu but am unable to use windows. It says some files are having error in the boot manager.
After a little research I installed the boot-repair and just found a summary of the system.

Here the link to the summary.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/10554334/

PS: please help

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try below and check,,, http://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-window-linux-boot-problems-with-super-grub-disk/

www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lkz2Q_F77lM

supergrubdisk (user friendly gui interface) to recover both windows can be used to recover windows bootloader most of the time..

http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wizard-restore-grub-with-super-grub2-disk/

or

www.supergrubdisk.org/wizard-restore-grub-with-rescatux/

and also check this if you cant do it from above.. 
sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/

I have not used boot repair cd by my self, but I just happened to read a comment made by user in sourceforge regarding boot repair cd... "Has worked in a few different scenarios. Fixed boot issues for various versions of Windows and Linux. Impressive. Looking at other reviews, it's a shame there's no version with support for older CPUs. Lets have some new releases please :-) thanks very much"

Comment: check the latest edit of my post...